# Getting string parameters using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a regex that can extract data from

```
BAYARPLN ke 116160029354, SUKSES. Hrg: 84.822. SN: TGK IMUM M SAMIN/R1/450/MAR,APR/Rp.89222/Adm6000/977-1071/047421CA414149E5CEC5. Saldo: 7
```

and I want to find this value like this...

```
977-1071
```

I tried to using parameter regex link this

```
"/(Adm6000)([^\7]+)/"
```

But I cant find the string regex `977-1071`. Can I ask for help for this?

Comment: Looking at the 7 in your regex, it's not clear to me what you're trying to match. Are you looking for any ddd-dddd where ddd-dddd follows Adm6000/ literally, or something with 7s specifically? I'm looking at a pattern like `Adm6000\/(\d{3}-\d{4})\/`.

Comment: `\d{1,}-\d{1,}`  Isn't this applicable for capturing a house number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this? see regex https://regex101.com/r/tccJ42/1

```js
const regex = /\d+\-\d+/g; //use \d{3}\-\d{4} if you've digit limit
const str = `BAYARPLN ke 116160029354, SUKSES. Hrg: 84.822. SN: TGK IMUM M SAMIN/R1/450/MAR,APR/Rp.89222/Adm6000/977-1071/047421CA414149E5CEC5. Saldo: 7`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match `977-1071` after `/Adm6000/` you could first match `/Adm6000/` and then capture in a group not a forward slash one or more times `([^/]+)`

[`\/Adm6000\/([^/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/qtCLyR/1)

Your value `977-1071` will be in captured group 1:

```js
const regex = /Adm6000\/([^/]+)/;
const str = `BAYARPLN ke 116160029354, SUKSES. Hrg: 84.822. SN: TGK IMUM M SAMIN/R1/450/MAR,APR/Rp.89222/Adm6000/977-1071/047421CA414149E5CEC5. Saldo: 7`;
let match = regex.exec(str);
console.log(match[1]);
```